# how to set up cognito identity pool in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am completely new to aws cognito, and these guides are all over the place and i am kind of lost. In my aws account i have made an identity pool, and now i want to try to create a new user from my android app, but it fails to create user or fails to connect to the cognito pool. I am not sure if i am doing this write and hope for your guidance!

Here is what i have so far.

```
public class aws extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText firstName,lastName,email,password;
    private Button loginButton;
    private String poolId,clientId,clientSecret;
    CognitoUserPool userPool;
    CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new
                CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // Context
                "IDENTITY POOL_ID", // Identity Pool ID
                MY_REGION // Region
        );
        CognitoSyncManager syncClient = new CognitoSyncManager(
                getApplicationContext(), // Context
                MY_REGION, // Region
                credentialsProvider
        );
        Dataset dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("myDataset");
        dataset.put("myKey", "myValue");
        dataset.synchronize(new DefaultSyncCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Dataset dataset, List newRecords) {
                //Your handler code here
            }
        });

        poolId = "MY_POOL_ID";
        clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
        clientSecret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        // Create a CognitoUserPool object to refer to your user pool
        userPool = new CognitoUserPool(getBaseContext(), poolId, clientId, clientSecret, clientConfiguration);

        bindActivity();
    }
    private void bindActivity()
    {
        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_firstNameET);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_lastNameET);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_emailET);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_passwordET);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.intro_register_zivit_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                setUpCognito();
            }
        });
    }
    private void setUpCognito()
    {
        // Create a CognitoUserAttributes object and add user attributes
         userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
        // Add the user attributes. Attributes are added as key-value pairs

        // Adding user's given name.
        // Note that the key is "given_name" which is the OIDC claim for given name
        userAttributes.addAttribute("given_name", firstName.getText().toString());

        // Adding user's lastName
        userAttributes.addAttribute("family_Name", lastName.getText().toString());
        // Adding user's email address
        userAttributes.addAttribute("email", email.getText().toString());

        setUpCognitoHandler();

    }

    private void setUpCognitoHandler()
    {
        SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails)
            {
                Log.d("myCognito","sign up succeeded!");
                // Sign-up was successful

                // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
                if(!userConfirmed)
                {
                    Log.d("myCognito","not confirmed! Need to confirm");
                    confirmUser();
                    // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
                    // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
                    // Get the confirmation code from user
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("myCognito","confirmed!");
                    // The user has already been confirmed
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception)
            {
                Log.d("myCognito","sign up failed!");
                // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
            }
        };
        userPool.signUpInBackground("user1ID", password.getText().toString(), userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
    }

    private void confirmUser()
    {
        // Callback handler for confirmSignUp API
        GenericHandler confirmationCallback = new GenericHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // User was successfully confirmed
                Log.d("myCognito","Confirmed User Success!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                // User confirmation failed. Check exception for the cause.
                Log.d("myCognito","Confirmed User faileure :(");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Again im really confused on how to make this class, when i used mobile hub, the code was all over the place in the sample app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Document [Amazon Cognito Credentials Provider](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-amazon-cognito-credentials-provider/)

In Mobile hub look for this file `CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider`

It has all the details how the sign in works

Below is the Authenctication Handler *(I have commented few things to remove errors)*

```
private AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final CognitoUserSession userSession, final CognitoDevice newDevice) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Logged in. " + userSession.getIdToken());

        cognitoUserSession = userSession;

        if (null != resultsHandler) {
            ViewHelper.showDialog(activity, activity.getString(title_activity_sign_in),
                    activity.getString(login_success) + " " + userSession.getIdToken());

            resultsHandler.onSuccess(CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.this);
        }

        initializedLatch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void getAuthenticationDetails(
            final AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, final String userId) {

        if (null != username && null != password) {
            final AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(
                    username,
                    password,
                    null);

            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        initializedLatch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void getMFACode(final MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {
        multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation = continuation;

        //todo uncomment it
       /* final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MFAActivity.class);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MFA_REQUEST_CODE);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticationChallenge(final ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported in this sample.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Exception exception) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to login.", exception);

        if (null != resultsHandler) {
            ViewHelper.showDialog(activity, activity.getString(R.string.title_activity_sign_in),
                    "Failed" + " " + exception);
            // activity.getString(  //todo uncomment it) + " " + exception);

                    resultsHandler.onError(CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.this, exception);
        }

        initializedLatch.countDown();
    }
};
```

This is the onClick Listener

```
@Override
    public View.OnClickListener initializeSignInButton(final Activity signInActivity,
                                                       final View buttonView,
                                                       final IdentityManager.SignInResultsHandler resultsHandler) {

        this.activity = signInActivity;
        this.resultsHandler = resultsHandler;

        // User Pools requires sign in with the username or verified channel.
        // Mobile Hub does not set up email verification because it requires SES verification.
        // Hence, prompt customers to login using the username or phone number.
        final EditText emailField = (EditText) activity.findViewById(EDIT_TEXT_USERNAME_ID);
        emailField.setHint(R.string.button_text_sign_in);


        final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                username = ViewHelper.getStringValue(activity, EDIT_TEXT_USERNAME_ID);
                password = ViewHelper.getStringValue(activity, EDIT_TEXT_PASSWORD_ID);

                final CognitoUser cognitoUser = cognitoUserPool.getUser(username);

                cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
            }
        };

        buttonView.setOnClickListener(listener);
        return listener;
    }
```

Comment: Try this github sample code also https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo